# Why won't these options menu indicators go away?

Tags: kingdom-hearts-3

While playing Kingdom Hearts 3 and I go to the options menu there are orange indicators on the menu items that show me I have stuff to do/look at (this image was taken from [here](https://www.flickr.com/photos/oneangrygamer/46190328954/in/dateposted-public/)):

[image]

However, when I go in and view everything in there, the indicator doesn't go away. Even after closing the menu and re-opening it. So, I'm getting what I think is a false sense that I've missed something (or perhaps I really have).

Is there a way in the sub sections to see what all I may have missed? Or, is this just a bug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The indicator only disappears once you went into every sub-menu and inspected (highlighted with your cursor) every sub-item and after closing the menu completely, i.e. go back to game so you have to press the menu button again to reopen the menu screen.

You will be able to see a small difference between the indicators that have been inspected versus the new ones. The ones you have not yet inspected are slightly brighter than the others.

Comment: I'll have to check this out again. I'm pretty sure I did that already, and the indicator still showed. I will be able to check tonight and let you know - Thanks,

Comment: FWIW, this was also the case in previous KH games. I will say though it is more difficult to tell the difference in KH3

Comment: yes, it is a very faint difference in this game.

Comment: I just tried and didn’t work. I’ve gone through every menu item and the indicators just don’t go away, even on items, abilities, and even lucky emblems. So odd.

Comment: I figured it out. You have to exit the menu system all the way, only then when you go back will it clear the indicator. If you’d like to append your answer I will mark it as accepted as the information you provided is also relevant

Comment: That is what I meant by "closing the menu completely", but I added some explanation to make it clearer.

Comment: Thanks, I thought I had done that but apparently I was mistaken. To me, it would make more sense to have it flag the item as 'read' as soon as you view it. Oh well. Thanks again